# do while loop doesn't get out of the loop?

Tags: java, do-while

I'm pretty sure this should work...
But even if I enter a 0 or a 1 it still asks me to pick a colour.
Am I being stupid or should it be exiting the loop if I enter a 0 or a 1?

```
public static int setColour() {
    EasyReader keyboard = new EasyReader();
    int colour;
    do{
        colour = keyboard.readInt("Pick a colour (black = 0, white = 1): ");
    }while (colour != 0 || colour != 1);
    return colour;
}
```

Comment: You need and (&&), not or (||)

Comment: read online about conditional operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both conditions will never be satisfied simultaneously using the `||` operator. You want

```
} while (colour != 0 && colour != 1);
```

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought using && meant 0 AND 1 to make it exit the loop and || meant either 0 OR 1 to exit the loop.. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using || will never return the correct result. The && operator however will return your answer accurate.